# Selling 3 maps to obtain specific map of next tier (atlas 3.9+)

Tags: path-of-exile

Vendoring 3x maps will yield a map of +1 tier. Before watchstones update (atlas change in 3.9) the result was always a single predefined map. Now it's one of many maps and I am trying to figure out the rules.

I've found [this helpful spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zz5l-2AZJYqmokSB5kbPBj2LEPa64wISDCELJAJ0674), to example, selling 3x T1 Warf maps may yield one of following up T2 maps:

- Alleyways
- Cursed Crypt
- Laboratory
- Strand

Let's say I need Cursed Crypt map. How do I get it?

I figured out it's a function from item unique ID.

Currently I am putting all Warf maps in my inventory. To example I have 5 maps and I am putting them like on screenshot below and then I am trying to sell 3 of them by control-clicking map in inventory (always from top to bottom):

[image]

which can be seen as binary bits: `11100`. So I am trying all unordered combinations possible, with following real outcome:

```
11100 -> Laboratory
11010 -> Strand
11001 -> Laboratory
10110 -> Strand
10101 -> Alleyways
10011 -> Alleyways
```

How do I get Cursed Crypt map. Do I miss some other parameter of that function?

Comment: What makes you think you can get Cursed Crypt with those three maps? There is no guarantee given that there is an ordering that produces Cursed Crypt. You might need to use another Wharf map.

Comment: @Polygnome, from these 5 maps you mean? Of course I can wait until I get another Wharf map and then try again all combinations. But I was hoping there are more parameters to that function or something I am doing is not correct. I can't find anything official, but if answer is NO (with link to a trustful source), sure, that would be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vendor recipes are not documented officially, but you can find information on them in the community-maintained wiki on this page:

[PoE Wiki/Vendor Recipe System](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vendor_recipe_system)

After 3.5.0, the outcome of the recipe became *randomized*. There is no guarantee to get any particular map, and there is no mention anywhere that the function is *total*.

In fact, the spreadsheet you provided gives multiple tiers with more than six maps. If you happen to have three Tier 10 Wharf maps, you can combine them in six different ways (3*2*1), but there are eight possible outcomes. This shows that totality is impossible. it is even worse for other tiers (T14 has 13 possible outcomes, more then twice the number of combinations available).

Your assumption that you can get every map from a higher tier with an arbitrary combination of three of one map in a lower tier is unfounded.

So to answer your question:

> How do I get Cursed Crypt map. Do I miss some other parameter of that function?

Get another Wharf map and combine it with all possible combinations of two of the three maps you already have.

Comment: That's the N1 page on wiki you have linked. I was there in fact and they say at the bottom: *"3.5.0 Different combinations of maps for the 3x maps to a +1 tiered map vendor recipe can now lead to different map in return. (Undocumented)"*. Notice word "undocumented", there is no official statement. Not sure where you get word "randomized", to me 3 maps with their unique items ID form as *seed* which is used to initiliaze random function, so outcome is guaranteed to be the same, but can't be determined. In other words your bottom line is what I expect: get more maps, try again all combos. Thanks

Comment: @Sinatr I think my usage of the word *randomized* is perfectly proper. See https://xkcd.com/221/. Of course we are talking about pseudo-randomness here, not true randomness... And it is still random even when a seed is used, just the time at which the outcome is determined is not when you trade it, but when the unique id is assigned to the item. On a side note, i have no idea what "N1 page" is supposed to mean.

Comment: N1 page - number one page - the first bookmarked page since I start playing PoE (because of its weird currency mechanics). It should be N1 for everyone.